Starting Winget and Winupdate-Scripts via Task Scheduler
I am trying to run a PowerShell script using Task Scheduler on Windows 10. The script runs without errors when executed manually. However, when it is deployed with Task Scheduler, it gets stuck in a loop and no results are achieved.The install script for the necessary runtimes and other dependencies is deployed via Baramundi.
I have tried using different start parameters and various user accounts (system, admin) to run the script. The goal is to start this script without user interaction and have it run at system startup.I also tried using a .bat script to start the PowerShell script indirectly, but it ends up in the same loop. The .bat file can successfully start the PowerShell script when triggered manually.
wingetscript: winget upgrade --all --accept-package-agreements --accept-source-agreements
winupdatescript: Install-WindowsUpdate -MicrosoftUpdate -AcceptAll -AutoReboot
Runtime Install Script:
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force -Confirm:$false
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine -Force
Set-PSRepository -Name 'PSGallery' -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate -Confirm:$False -Force
Set-PSRepository -Name 'PSGallery' -InstallationPolicy Untrusted
Remove-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinUpdatesInstall.ps1"
Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "WinUpdateInstall" -Confirm:$false
Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted -Scope LocalMachine -Force
